# How to update tab with Background.js and THEN execute Content Script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like for my Chrome extension to run like this:

User clicks on the icon and that brings up the hard-coded URL, "www.example.com". It does not open a new tab but instead updates the window. I would then like to execute the content script and be able to alert "working" on the updated page.

Here is what i've got so far:

**Background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
 chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function 
 (tabs) 
    {

chrome.tabs.update({
 url: "http://www.example.com/"
});
});
function test()
{
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "myscript.js"}); 

}




chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeinfo, tab) {
var url = tab.url;
    if (url !== undefined && changeinfo.status == "complete") {

    test();
}
});
});
```

**Content script**

```
alert('working');
```

The result is odd. When I click on the icon, it brings up example.com fine, however sometimes the alert works and sometimes it doesn't. Even weirder, it works more often if I double click but if I click it a bunch of times, the alerts add up and i then get many alerts all at once (I just want one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **content.js** can set a global variable so you can check it to skip reinjection.

  ```
  if (window[chrome.runtime.id]) {
    alert('Oi! Reinjected.');
  } else {
    window[chrome.runtime.id] = true;
    alert('Oi!');
  }

  // do something
  ```

  Depending on what you do in the content script, you can add a [message listener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) which will process requests from your background page instead of re-running the entire code.
- **background.js** checks if the active tab is already navigated to the site of interest (or navigates to it) and injects the content script (comment out `inject();` to skip reinjection).

  The check itself is simple: inject a content script code that checks that global variable. This code runs in the same context as other content scripts for a given page (the [*isolated world*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment)).

  ```
  const SITE_URL = 'http://www.example.com';

  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
    if (tab.url === new URL(SITE_URL).href) {
      checkIfInjected(tab).then(tab => {
        console.log('already injected in %d, reinjecting anyway', tab.id);
        inject(tab);
      }).catch(inject);
    } else {
      updateTabAndWaitForStart(tab.id, {url: SITE_URL})
        .then(inject);
    }
  });

  function checkIfInjected(tab) {
    return runContentScript(tab.id, {
      code: 'window[chrome.runtime.id]',
    }).then(results => {
      resolve(results[0] ? tab : Promise.reject(tab));
    });
  }

  function inject(tab) {
    return runContentScript(tab.id, {
      file: 'content.js',
      runAt: 'document_end',
      allFrames: false,
    });
  }

  function runContentScript(tabId, options) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, options, resolve);
    });
  }
  ```

  ```
  // onUpdated listener waits for our tab to get an URL, detaches on success
  ```

  ```
  function updateTabAndWaitForStart(tabId, options) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      chrome.tabs.update(tabId, options, newTab => {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
          function onUpdated(updatedId, info, updatedTab) {
            if (updatedId === newTab.id && info.url) {
              chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onUpdated);
              resolve(updatedTab);
            }
          }
        );
      });
    });
  }
  ```
- **manifest.json** should contain permissions for the site you navigate to and for the active tab.

  Of course, a larger permission like `<all_urls>` would include these, but the advantage of an exact list is that the installation warning in the extensions web store will show only the site.

  `*` in the site URL permission is optional (works the same as per API design).
  The final `/` is mandatory (it's a path).

  ```
  {
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": ".............",
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "click me"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "http://www.example.com/*"]
  }
  ```